# Why I am getting RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration? and how to solve it?

Tags: python, nltk

I am making Bigrams of the tokens stored in list docToken.

```
print(docToken[520])
```

> Output: ['sleepy', 'account', 'just', 'man', 'tired', 'twitter', 'case',
>   'romney', 'candidate', 'looks']

```
list(nltk.bigrams(docToken[520]))
```

> Output: [('sleepy', 'account'),  ('account', 'just'),  ('just', 'man'), 
>   ('man', 'tired'),  ('tired', 'twitter'),  ('twitter', 'case'), 
>   ('case', 'romney'),  ('romney', 'candidate'),  ('candidate', 'looks')]

and when i'm using `nltk.bigrams(docToken[i])` in a loop i'm getting following error on the range>=1000:

```
bigram=[]
for i in range(5000):
    ls=list(nltk.bigrams(docToken[i]))
    for j in ls:
        bigram.append(list(j))
```

it's working just fine when the range(500) in the first loop but when the Range is 1000 or more it is giving me following error:

```
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last) 
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\util.py in ngrams(sequence, n, pad_left, 
  pad_right, left_pad_symbol, right_pad_symbol)
        467     while n > 1:
    --> 468         history.append(next(sequence))
        469         n -= 1

StopIteration: 

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-8982951528bd> in <module>()
      1 bigram=[]
      2 for i in range(5000):
----> 3     ls=list(nltk.bigrams(docToken[i]))
      4     for j in ls:
      5         bigram.append(list(j))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\util.py in bigrams(sequence, **kwargs)
    489     """
    490 
--> 491     for item in ngrams(sequence, 2, **kwargs):
    492         yield item
    493 

RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: I am using python 3.7.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was not able to resolve this error. Not sure why `nltk.bigrams(docToken[i])` is generating this but I was able to create bigrams by using the following code.

```
bigram={}
for i in range(size):
    ls=[]
    for j in range(len(docToken[i])-1):
        for k in range(j,len(docToken[i])-1):
            ls.append([docToken[i][j],docToken[i][k+1]])

    bigram[i]=ls
```

Answer (score 4):

I too faced the same error. One possible reason can be that one of the elements in `docToken` is an empty list.

For example, the following code throws the same error when `i=2` as the second element is an empty list.

```
from nltk import bigrams
docToken= [['the', 'wildlings', 'are', 'dead'], [], ['do', 'the', 'dead', 'frighten', 'you', 'ser', 'waymar']]
for i in range(3):
    print (i)
    print (list(nltk.bigrams(docToken[i])))
```

Output:

```
0
[('the', 'wildlings'), ('wildlings', 'are'), ('are', 'dead')]
1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\util.py in ngrams(sequence, n, pad_left, pad_right, left_pad_symbol, right_pad_symbol)
    467     while n > 1:
--> 468         history.append(next(sequence))
    469         n -= 1

StopIteration: 

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-91f35cae32ed> in <module>
      2 for i in range(3):
      3     print (i)
----> 4     list(nltk.bigrams(docToken[i]))

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\util.py in bigrams(sequence, **kwargs)
    489     """
    490 
--> 491     for item in ngrams(sequence, 2, **kwargs):
    492         yield item
    493 

RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

You can filter out the empty lists from `docToken` and then create bigrams:

```
docToken= [['the', 'wildlings', 'are', 'dead'], [], ['do', 'the', 'dead', 'frighten', 'you', 'ser', 'waymar']]
docToken = [x for x in docToken if x]
bigram = []
for i in range(len(docToken)):
    bigram.append(["_".join(w) for w in  bigrams(docToken[i])])
bigram
```

Output:

```
[['the_wildlings', 'wildlings_are', 'are_dead'],
 ['do_the',
  'the_dead',
  'dead_frighten',
  'frighten_you',
  'you_ser',
  'ser_waymar']]
```

Another possible reason can be that you're using `nltk` 3.3 in python 3.7.

> Please use nltk 3.4, it's the first version with Python 3.7 support, your issue should be resolved in this version.

Please see [here](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/2223).

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by upgrading nltk from 3.3 -> 3.4

Do simple:

```
pip install nltk==3.4
```

Answer (score 2):

First uninstall the current version of NLTK

```
pip uninstall nltk==3.2.5
```

Then install the latest version of NLTK

```
pip install nltk==3.6.2
```

And then check NLTK version, it should be 3.6.2

```
import nltk
print('The nltk version is {}.'.format(nltk.__version__))
```

This will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To complete @Leonard answer, I've solved it by uninstalling and reinstalling simply with:

```
pip uninstall nltk
pip install nltk
```

Don't give version numbers, by default it uninstalls the one you have and reinstall the latest one.